# irq disabled api in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel how to determine whether an interrupt is disabled ? Because enable the interrupt need to balance，if there is api, not `irqs_disabled()`.

Because enable the interrupt need to balance，if I force to enable the kernel will report a warning.I know the depth -- or ++ may be useful.

Comment: Can you reword the question?  It's very vague and hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Every interrupt service routine and every kernel code which disables interrupts is required to reenable interrupts.  There should be exactly a one to one ratio.

Reenabling interrupts should not be conditional.  If it is, there are some deep problems in the logic of added components.